# outlookのVBA でマクロを作成しましたが、仕分け設定の「スクリプトを実行する」に作成したマクロが出てきません。

Tags: vba, batch-file

"実行例1" のようにマクロを作成しましたが、電子メールの仕分け設定（処理選択画面）で「スクリプトを実行する」を選択したところ、作成したマクロが出てこない状況です。

また、コードを書き加えたところ作成したマクロが「スクリプトを実行する」に出てきますが、
マクロの実行ができません（"実行例2" を参照）。

すでに試したことは３つです。

- マクロのセキュリティレベルを最大限下げる。
- マクロがデジタル署名されていることを確認。
- Publicを外しても同じでした

今週初めて触った初心者のため単純な構文のミスかもしれませんが、調べても解決できず困っています。ご教授いただければ幸いです。

#### 実行例1

マクロは実行できるが、電子メールの仕分け設定（処理選択画面）で「スクリプトを実行する」に表示されない

```
Public Sub RunBatFile() 

　Dim sPath As String  

　sPath = "C:\python\bbb.cmd" 
 
　Shell sPath, vbHide 

End Sub
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 実行例2

マクロが実行できないが、電子メールの仕分け設定（処理選択画面）で「スクリプトを実行する」に表示される

```
Public Sub RunBatFile(Item As Outlook.MailItem) 

 Dim sPath As String 

 sPath = "C:\python\bbb.cmd" 

 Shell sPath, vbHide 

End Sub
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]